# Activity indicator not loading correctly

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using an activity indicator to show to the user while the code goes away and calls to azure. 
The call itself works fine and all is working well but the activity indicator loads for a set period of time then afterwards the same delay that I'm trying to prevent to the user still takes place then the next screen loads. 
I should probably clarify that I'm relatively new to Xamarin and a lot of this async/await stuff alludes me.
I have put the API calls in a Task and put an await method called sleep in there that runs for about 4 seconds. This was the only way I could get it to run the activity indicator. But it looks like this is also causing the problem, so to summarise I'm stuck.
I want the calls to Azure to take place while the activity indicator is going then when they return open the next page, so as to prevent page lagging and freezing. It does not look good.
So, this is the method that calls to the APIs:

```
private async Task HandleSubmitCommand()
{
        //if (IsLoading) return;
        IsLoading = true;

        await Sleep();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdentityDriver))
            {

                _entryFieldType = "oid";
                _statusResponse = DependencyService.Get<IWebService>().Login(_entryFieldType, IdentityDriver, App.TenantId.Value.ToString());
                IsLoading = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _entryFieldType = "rid";
                _statusResponse = DependencyService.Get<IWebService>().Login(_entryFieldType, IdentityRoute, App.TenantId.Value.ToString());
            }


        if (_statusResponse == "True")
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new DriverDashboardView();

        }
        else
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NotFoundView();

}
```

This is the sleep method:

```
    private Task Sleep()
    {
        return Task.Delay(4000);
    }
```

This is the Login method that calls to the API:

```
public string Login(string ID, string IDPayload, string TenantID)
    {
        //await Sleep();
        var BaseURL = App.ConFigURL;
        var URI = string.Format(BaseURL, TenantID);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URI);

            var Telemetry = new { typeid = ID , id = IDPayload};
            var Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Telemetry);
            var SAS = DependencyService.Get<ISasToken>().CreateToken(URI, "RootManageSharedAccessKey", "#####################################");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", SAS);
            var Content = new StringContent(Payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


            var Response = httpClient.PostAsync(URI,Content).Result;

            return Response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();

        }
    }
```

As I stated the calls to Azure are fine but it doesn't seem to be running asynchronously. It doesn't help that I'm not at all comfortable with async/await.
An ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the calls to Azure to take place while the activity indicator is going then when they return open the next page, so as to prevent page lagging and freezing.

The `await Sleep();` under your `HandleSubmitCommand` method is unnecessary. At this point, your login operation would be executed after 4s. Based on your 
`Login` method, you exexute the login operation synchronously via `httpClient.PostAsync(URI,Content).Result`. You could modify your methods as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> Login(string ID, string IDPayload, string TenantID)
{
   .
   .
   var Response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI,Content);
   return Response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}

private async Task HandleSubmitCommand()
{
   IsBusy = true;
   //call the login operation asynchronously
   _statusResponse = await DependencyService.Get<IWebService>().Login(_entryFieldType, IdentityDriver, App.TenantId.Value.ToString());
   IsBusy = false;
}
```

**Note:** You need to change the definition for your `IWebService` interface as follows:

```
public interface IWebService
{
   Task<bool> Login(string ID, string IDPayload, string TenantID);
}
```